# How to do jquery code AFTER page loading?

Tags: jquery

> If you want an event to work on your
>   page, you should call it inside the
>   $(document).ready() function.
>   Everything inside it will load as soon
>   as the DOM is loaded and **before**
>   the page contents are loaded.

I want to do javascript code only **after** the page contents are loaded how can I do that?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Use `load` instead of `ready`:

```
$(document).load(function () {
 // code here
});
```

**Update**
You need to use `.on()` since jQuery 1.8. (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
 // code here
});
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817448/jquery-replacement-for-deprecated-load/37817516#37817516):

> According to http://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/:
>
> > #### Removed deprecated event aliases
> >
> > `.load`, `.unload`, and `.error`, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, are no
> >     more. Use `.on()` to register listeners.
> >
> > https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2286

Comment: From the comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37817516/957246

    $(window).on("load", function() {
      // code here
    });

..because ".load" is deprecated.

Comment: using .on() it's so obvious.. but I spent 1h knocking my head against the wall before finding this.. thank you..!

Comment: Watch out for the mistake of trying `$(document).on('load', ...` it needs to be `$(window).on('load',...`

Answer (score 45):

nobody mentioned this

```
$(function() {
    // place your code
});
```

which is a shorthand function of

```
$(document).ready(function() { .. });
```

Answer (score 40):

Following

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
});
```

can be replaced

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
     // insert your code here 
});
```

There is one more way which I'm using to increase the page load time.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(window).load(function() { 
     //insert all your ajax callback code here. 
     //Which will run only after page is fully loaded in background.
  });
});
```

Comment: a load handler in the ready handler? That's madness.You don't need the document ready since window does exist at that point and you can attach a handler without it.

Comment: The load handler inside the ready handler does not work as of jQuery 3.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48718000/4564945

Comment: It is a very old answer. Check the alternative function for jquery 3.0

Answer (score 20):

You can avoid get undefined in '$' this way

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    // Your code
});
```

**EDIT:** Using 'DOMContentLoaded' is faster than just 'load' because load wait page fully loaded, imgs included... while DomContentLoaded waits just the structure

Answer (score 19):

Edit: This code will wait until all content (images and scripts) are fully loaded and rendered in the browser.

I've had this problem where `$(window).on('load',function(){ ... })` would fire too quick for my code since the *Javascript* I used was for formatting purposes and hiding elements. The elements where hidden too soon and where left with a height of 0.

I now use `$(window).on('pageshow',function(){ //code here });` and it fires at the time I need.

Comment: This one helped me too, I exactly wanted to run some code after the jQuery Mobile page was displayed. Thank you. @Boyd Cyr

Comment: Just wanted to add how much more helpful this code is compared to the accepted answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

I am looking for the same problem and here is what help me.
Here is the jQuery version 3.1.0 and the **load event is deprecated for use since jQuery version 1.8**. The load event is removed from jQuery 3.0. Instead, you can use on method and bind the JavaScript load event:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  alert("Window Loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 7):

And if you want to run a second function after the first one finishes, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/javascript-jquery-call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete).

Answer (score 7):

write the code that you want to be executed inside this. When your document is ready, this will be executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

});
```