# Wait till a Function with animations is finished until running another Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm having an issue with normal (**non-ajax**) functions that involve lots of **animations** within each of them. Currently I simply have a `setTimeout` between functions, but this isn't perfect since no browsers / computers are the same.

**Additional Note: They both have separate animations/etc that collide.**

I can't simply put one in the callback function of another

```
// multiple dom animations / etc
FunctionOne();

// What I -was- doing to wait till running the next function filled
// with animations, etc

setTimeout(function () { 
    FunctionTwo(); // other dom animations (some triggering on previous ones)
}, 1000);
```

Is there anyway in js/jQuery to have:

```
// Pseudo-code
-do FunctionOne()
-when finished :: run -> FunctionTwo()
```

I know about `$.when()` & `$.done()`, but those are for AJAX...

---

- **MY UPDATED SOLUTION**

jQuery has an exposed variable (that for some reason isn't listed anywhere in the jQuery docs) called $.timers, which holds the array of animations currently taking place.

```
function animationsTest (callback) {
    // Test if ANY/ALL page animations are currently active

    var testAnimationInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (! $.timers.length) { // any page animations finished
            clearInterval(testAnimationInterval);
            callback();
        }
    }, 25);
};
```

Basic useage:

```
// run some function with animations etc    
functionWithAnimations();

animationsTest(function () { // <-- this will run once all the above animations are finished

    // your callback (things to do after all animations are done)
    runNextAnimations();

});
```

Comment: If `FunctionOne` doesn't has a timeout or anything, you can just call `FunctionOne(); FunctionTwo();`, can't you?

Comment: The problem is that they both have separate animations/etc, in different files - etc. So they end up colliding...

Comment: @arxanas - Yes JavaScript is single threaded, but I suspect he wants to chain two functions together so that one always fires with the other.

Comment: `$.when` and `$.done` aren't necessarily just for ajax. If you have various asynchronous tasks in FunctionOne that you want to have finish before firing off FunctionTwo, you can create `Deferred` objects, put them in an array, call `resolve()` on each when the action is done, and then do `$.when.apply($, array).then(function(){...});`

Comment: globals are evil, but in this case it _might_ be worth just adding a `isRunning` flag.

Comment: This very much depends on the content of the functions!

Comment: You saved my app, I am eternally grateful

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
var FunctionOne = function () {
  // create a deferred object
  var r = $.Deferred();

  // do whatever you want (e.g. ajax/animations other asyc tasks)

  setTimeout(function () {
    // and call `resolve` on the deferred object, once you're done
    r.resolve();
  }, 2500);

  // return the deferred object
  return r;
};

// define FunctionTwo as needed
var FunctionTwo = function () {
  console.log('FunctionTwo');
};

// call FunctionOne and use the `done` method
// with `FunctionTwo` as it's parameter
FunctionOne().done(FunctionTwo);
```

you could also pack multiple deferreds together:

```
var FunctionOne = function () {
  var
    a = $.Deferred(),
    b = $.Deferred();

  // some fake asyc task
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('a done');
    a.resolve();
  }, Math.random() * 4000);

  // some other fake asyc task
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('b done');
    b.resolve();
  }, Math.random() * 4000);

  return $.Deferred(function (def) {
    $.when(a, b).done(function () {
      def.resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p22dK/

Comment: As he said he uses animations, you might want to mention jQuery's `.promise()` method for the fx queue

Comment: @Bergi You mean that jQuery returns a deferred object from `animate`? For otherwise I don't really see the need for the promise object here.

Comment: Yes, I did not meant the `Deferred.promise`, but the jQuery method http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Oh wow just reading all this now Yoshi, good stuff! I'm going to give these a go - tomorrow, and try to mess around with .promise as well. Appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I finally got a chance to read more about deferred / done / promise / when, etc. And these are PERFECT! They literally wait till all animations are done on a set thing. when($('whatever')).done() works perfect!

Comment: ^ you don't need any special object to wait for an animation to complete. Just use $(something).animate({animation}, duration, callback(){}). callback will be executed only when the animation is done.

Comment: The problem is that these functions have tons of animations within themselves, callbacks aren't possible in this situation. @Saturnix

Comment: Is it really a solution?  I think that functionality comes from timeout function usage, not use of done(), am I wrong? If you remove timeout is it still working?

Comment: @mrarm the `setTimeout` is just a proof-of-concept. Any other async-method that triggers the `.resolve` method would work.

Comment: I don't get it. When I delete part with timeout() second function is launched before first function ends. I'm trygin it on my code (first function is creating many divs) and i want to launch second after all elements are created. I must dig into it :)

Comment: @mram Just open a real question, people will help you then ;)  (You could include that you tried this solution but are having problems with adepting it correclty.)

Comment: jQuery's on completes does not work for you? `$('selector').animate({...},OnCompleteFunctionName);`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the multiple Defers note you left... that helped me solve a problem I was having! Cheer brotha.

Comment: Is there a way to realize it with a recursive function with n-calls?
So for example I'm passing an array with n elements and for each element, there will be a recursive call, until the array is empty.

Comment: I think `FunctionOne().done(FunctionTwo);` should be `FunctionOne().done(FunctionTwo());`

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen If it were so, `FunctionTwo` would be called before `FunctionOne` and only it's return value would be passed to `.done()`.

Answer (score 13):

add the following to the end of the first function

```
return $.Deferred().resolve();
```

call both functions like so

```
functionOne().done(functionTwo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Along with Yoshi's answer, I have found another very simple (callback type) solution for animations.

jQuery has an exposed variable (that for some reason isn't listed anywhere in the jQuery docs) called **$.timers**, which holds the array of animations currently taking place.

```
function animationsTest (callback) {
    // Test if ANY/ALL page animations are currently active

    var testAnimationInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (! $.timers.length) { // any page animations finished
            clearInterval(testAnimationInterval);
            callback();
        }
    }, 25);
};
```

**Basic useage:**

```
functionOne(); // one with animations

animationsTest(functionTwo);
```

Hope this helps some people out!

Answer (score 2):

### This answer uses [`promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), a JavaScript feature of the `ECMAScript 6` standard. If your target platform does not support `promises`, polyfill it with [PromiseJs](https://www.promisejs.org/).

You can get the `Deferred` object jQuery creates for the animation using `.promise()` on the animation call. Wrapping these `Deferreds` into [ES6 `Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) results in much cleaner code than using timers.

You can also use `Deferreds` directly, but this is generally discouraged because they do not follow the Promises/A+ specification.

The resulting code would look like this:

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve($('#Content').animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, { duration: 500, queue: false }).promise());
var p2 = Promise.resolve($('#Content').animate({ marginLeft: "-100px" }, { duration: 2000, queue: false }).promise());
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function () {
    return $('#Content').animate({ width: 0 }, { duration: 500, queue: false }).promise();
});
```

Note that the function in `Promise.all()` returns the promise. This is where magic happens. If in a `then` call a promise is returned, the next `then` call will wait for that promise to be resolved before executing.

jQuery uses an animation queue for each element. So animations on the same element are executed synchronously. In this case you wouldn't have to use promises at all!

I have disabled the jQuery animation queue to demonstrate how it would work with promises.

`Promise.all()` takes an array of promises and creates a new `Promise` that finishes after all promises in the array finished.

`Promise.race()` also takes an array of promises, but finishes as soon as the first `Promise` finished.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean man:  http://jsfiddle.net/LF75a/

You will have one function fire the next function and so on, i.e. add another function call and then add your `functionONe` at the bottom of it.

Please lemme know if I missed anything, hope it fits the cause `:)`

**or** this: [Call a function after previous function is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/javascript-jquery-call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete)

**Code:**

```
function hulk()
{
  // do some stuff...
}
function simpsons()
{
  // do some stuff...
  hulk();
}
function thor()
{
  // do some stuff...
  simpsons();
}
```

Comment: Callback is the appropriate JS answer, IMO.

Comment: All I have is a function call. I cannot modify the function, but I need to execute my other function after the first finishes.

Comment: I believe this wouldn't work with animation because they tend to have delays to work at the first place

Answer (score 1):

**ECMAScript 6 UPDATE**

This uses a new feature of JavaScript called Promises

functionOne().then(functionTwo);

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via callback function.

```
$('a.button').click(function(){
    if (condition == 'true'){
        function1(someVariable, function() {
          function2(someOtherVariable);
        });
    }
    else {
        doThis(someVariable);
    }
});
```

function function1(param, callback) {
  ...do stuff
  callback();
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for n-calls (recursive function).
https://jsfiddle.net/mathew11/5f3mu0f4/7/

```
function myFunction(array){
var r = $.Deferred();

if(array.length == 0){
    r.resolve();
    return r;
}

var element = array.shift();
// async task 
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $("a").text($("a").text()+ " " + element);
    var resolving = function(){
        r.resolve();
    }

    myFunction(array).done(resolving);

 }, 500);

return r;
}

//Starting the function
var myArray = ["Hi", "that's", "just", "a", "test"];
var alerting = function (){window.alert("finished!")};
myFunction(myArray).done(alerting);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript `Promise` and `async/await` to implement a synchronized call of the functions.

Suppose you want to execute `n` number of functions in a synchronized manner that are stored in an array, here is my solution for that.

```js
async function executeActionQueue(funArray) {
  var length = funArray.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    await executeFun(funArray[i]);
  }
};

function executeFun(fun) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    // Execute required function here
    
    fun()
      .then((data) => {
        // do required with data 
        resolve(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      // handle error
        resolve(true);
      });
  })
};

executeActionQueue(funArray);
```