# Vanilla JS: delay click event to add animation

Tags: javascript, animation

**No jQuery please!**

I would love not to use jQuery for this, because it's a big library and I only need to do this single thing:

I would like to add a short delay to a click event so I can fade elements off my page using CSS.

I could post all of the code I've tried so far, but you'd get bored. So here's the one that I think is the closest:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a').onclick = function (e) {

// Delay setting the location for one second
setTimeout(function() {this.href}, 90000);

var animOut = document.getElementByClassName('animateOut');
   animOut.className += 'out';
};
```

I've already ruled out using `onbeforeunload`, so hijacking the click event seems to be the best way.

Once again, I know this would be a doddle in jQuery, but I would like to avoid it if it's possible.

Thanks so much for your answers.

Ben

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to commenters guest271314 and The Alpha, I've settled on this approach, but still have yet to complete the puzzle.

```
window.onload = function(){

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for( var i=0,il = links.length; i< il; i ++ ){
 links[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}

function clickHandler(event) {

event.preventDefault();

// Delay setting the location for one second
setTimeout(function() {

  location.href = this.href;
}, 90000);

// add `s` to `Element`
var animOut = document.getElementsByClassName("animateOut");

// iterate `animOut` elements
for (var i = 0; i < animOut.length; i++) {
   // add `out` `className` to `animOut` element at index `i`
   animOut[i].classList.add("out");
};
};
};
```

Having to iterate over the `a` tags was an addition I have learned from reading other posts (I'll link to them in a minute).

Unfortunately, the `setTimeout` function doesn't seem to be working. I need to refine what's in this function, but don't know in what way.

Further assistance would be most welcome.

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really take credit for this, the 2 users below (guest271314 and The Alpha) deserve a lot of recognition for what they helped me to achieve. The full code, with a couple of refinements, is:

```
window.onload = function(){

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for( var i=0,il = links.length; i< il; i ++ ){
links[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}

function clickHandler(event) {

event.preventDefault();

var travelTo = this.getAttribute("href");

// add `s` to `Element`
var animOut = document.getElementsByClassName("animateOut");

// iterate `animOut` elements
for (var i = 0; i < animOut.length; i++) {
   // add `out` `className` to `animOut` element at index `i`
   animOut[i].classList.add("out");
};

// Delay page out until the animation finishes
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = travelTo;
}, 1000);
};
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a').onclick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementByClassName('animateOut').className += ' out';
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = this.href;
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment, that really validated my approach and got me thinking. I've added an update, if there's anything you'd like to add to help me refine my `setTimeout` function, I'd be grateful. If not, thanks so much for all you've done.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an `"s"` at [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) . To add `className` to all `animateOut` elements can use a `for` loop; change `this.href` to `window.location.href = e.target.href` if expected result is to navigate to `href` of clicked `a` element; else leave as `this.href` is requirement is to refresh current `window.location.href` : `this.href` within `setTimeout`

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").onclick = function (e) {

// Delay setting the location for one second
setTimeout(function() {window.location.href = this.href}, 90000);

// add `s` to `Element`
var animOut = document.getElementsByClassName("animateOut");
// iterate `animOut` elements
for (var i = 0; i < animOut.length; i++) {
   // add `out` `className` to `animOut` element at index `i`
   animOut[i].classList.add("out");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this has got a big piece of my puzzle together. If there's anything you can add to help me refine the `setTimeout` function, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @endymion1818 _"the `setTimeout` function doesn't seem to be working."_ What is expected result at `setTimeout` ? What does `this.href` represent ? The current URL of the document, or the `href` attribute of the clicked `a` element ?

Comment: Hi @guest271314, the desired result is for the `setTimeout` to activate the clicked location after a delay. Thanks :-)

Comment: @endymion1818 Have you tried substituting `event.target.href` for `this.href` within `setTimeout` ?

Answer (score 0):

Eight (08) years late to the party but here is what you need to do to introduce the delay anywhere in plain JavaScript.

This is the syntax:

```
setTimeout(() => { /*your fancy stuff here*/ }, DelayYouWantInMs);
```

For example, I want to show the "Loading..." for 2 seconds on my page to draw a dynamic HTML table when a button is clicked which further retrieves the data from an api.

Below is how you use above syntax:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(createTable)
            .catch(error => console.error(error));

    }, 2000);
```

And a full blown working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Build table from API response</h2>
    <button id="foo">Lets do it !</button>
</body>
<script>
    const button = document.querySelector('#foo');
    button.addEventListener('click', fetchData, false);

    function fetchData() {
        button.textContent = 'Loading...Please wait...';
        button.disabled = true;
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(createTable)
                .catch(error => console.error(error));

        }, 2000);
    }
    function getColumnHeadings(data) {
        return Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => {
            return `<td>${key}</td>`;
        }).join('');
    }
    function getRows(data) {
        return data.map(obj => {
            return `<tr>${getCells(obj)}</tr>`
        }).join('');
    }
    function getCells(obj) {
        return Object.values(obj).map(value => {
            return `<td>${value}</td>`;
        }).join('');
    }
    function createTable(data) {
        const headings = getColumnHeadings(data);
        const rows = getRows(data);
        const html = `<table><tbody><tr class="headings">${headings}</tr>${rows}</tbody></table>`
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
        button.remove();
    }
</script>
</html>
```