# function will work after some delay using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In my project, I have a button with onclick event. for that event, I have some function but I want that function should execute after some time. if any way to execute the function after some delay?

if anyone knows please share the answer with me.

Comment: Did you search your problem on Stackoverflow? It seems that this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690193/delaying-click-event fits to your needs

Answer (score 0):

For some time lag you can call your onclick function inside setTimeout, maybe that can help you.

```
function foo(){...}

setTimeout(foo, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a setTimeout() method?