# Calling JavaScript functions. First function waits for the other which intern having the one more function for confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two JavaScript function in two different files. On click I am calling first function to delete and second function for refresh the text in the div. The problem is delete function is having confirm action. So if I call one after the other refresh function is executing immediately. But I want refresh function to execute after confirmation (Note:delete and refresh JavaScript functions are there in two different projects)
Below is the sample:

```
function deleteIFAsset(a) {
    var id1 = a.id;
    IframeCloudEditor.deleteFileFromTimeline(id1);
    refreshAsseListt();
}
```

Comment: Deferred

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116505/wait-till-a-function-is-finished-until-running-another-function

 Callback

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/javascript-jquery-call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a callback. Any properly-designed library with asynchronous operations (like waiting for the user to confirm an action in an event-driven environment like a browser) should offer a callback for when that operation is complete. You haven't said what library the `deleteFileFromTimeline` comes from, but hopefully it offers a callback. The callback may be an argument you pass, or it may be part of a "promise" API.

**If** it accepts a callback directly, that would look something like this:

```
function deleteIFAsset(a) {
    var id1 = a.id;
    IframeCloudEditor.deleteFileFromTimeline(id1, function() {
        refreshAsseListt();
    });
}
```

or

```
function deleteIFAsset(a) {
    var id1 = a.id;
    IframeCloudEditor.deleteFileFromTimeline(id1, refreshAsseListt);
}
```

...if your `refreshAsseListt` (was that supposed to be `refreshAssetList`?) is compatible with what the library does with the callback (the arguments it passes to it and what it does with the return value).

If it returns a [promise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) instead, that would look something like this:

```
function deleteIFAsset(a) {
    var id1 = a.id;
    IframeCloudEditor.deleteFileFromTimeline(id1).then(refreshAsseListt);
}
```

("Promises" are also sometimes called "futures" or "deferred objects.")

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the code of deleteFileFromTimeLine, you can change it to return the result of the confirmation.
and execute refreshAsseListt.
example

```
function deleteFileFromTimeLine(ID)
{
...
return Confirm('Delete File?');
}
```

and change your code like this

```
function deleteIFAsset(a) {
    var id1 = a.id;
    if(IframeCloudEditor.deleteFileFromTimeline(id1))
{
    refreshAsseListt();
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are searching for a solution, to execute your javascript synchronous. But javascript is always executed synchronously except for special cases like ajax requests or file access.

[My advice is to use a callback function to solve this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function)