# How to ensure that one task happens only after another task ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Don't make it duplicate please. I am in middle of a big problem. I am working on a javascript code with thousands of lines of code. My problem is:

**methodA** is called from its own class.

```
methodA{  
    doSomething(abc, def, function(obj){  
        obj.getName();  
    });  
}  

doSomething(abc, def, callback){  
// codes....
callback(new XYZ());  
}
```

In XYZ class constructor I am using a couple of Jquery Deffered objects(with ajax calls). So my problem is at `obj.getName()` I am getting error that `this.name` is not defined. So how can I ensure that entire **new XYZ()** execution ends completely(all ajax calls, callbacks etc.) when the control comes to `obj.getName()` function ?

**Thanks**

Comment: can't you write the methodA in the callback of XYZ()?

Comment: First thing you gotta do is to write valid javascript!

Answer (score 1):

You can use function call back for this purpose. 
more can be searched on google by jquery deferred
As [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116505/wait-till-a-function-is-finished-until-running-another-function)

```
var jqDeferred = doSomething(abc,def,function(obj){

});

jqDeferred.done(function(){
obj.getName();  
})


doSomething(abc,def,callback)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .when and .then => http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
methodA{  
    doSomething(abc, def, function(obj){  
        $.when(callback(new XYZ())).then(obj.getName());  
    });
```