# Jquery can't trigger second scroll event

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery.visible

I am trying to get $(window).scroll to fire on a second element using .visible(). But if i  write it like i have done below or even put them in separate code blocks, which ever one is on top fires and the one underneath doesn't. It seems like window.scroll is still waiting for the first event to happen and ignores the second one?

```
   //***********************************************************
        // TEST ELEMENTS ARE IN VIEWPORT
        //***********************************************************
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($("#moreSection").visible(true)){
                $(".slideInLeft").delay(400).show("slide", { direction: "right", easing: 'easeOutBounce'}, 400);
            }else if($("#why-use-section").visible(true)) {
                $(".slideInLeft2").delay(400).show("slide", { direction: "right", easing: 'easeOutBounce'}, 1600);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Can you produce a JSfiddle?

Comment: hi , well im using .visible() to test if its in the viewport already. thanks :)

Comment: By second event, do you mean the #why-use-section element in the 'else if' statement? If you want that to be fired on scroll along with #moreSection, convert the 'else if' to a regular 'if'

Comment: i cant use jsfiddle because its using the jquery.visible.js plugin

Comment: Hi yes i tried that, 2 if's have the same result

Comment: im using this to test if elements are in the viewport:https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116505/wait-till-a-function-is-finished-until-running-another-function

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the right solution, but based on this: [Wait till a Function with animations is finished until running another Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116505/wait-till-a-function-is-finished-until-running-another-function)

```
function ScrollOne(){
    if ($("#moreSection").visible(true))
        $(".slideInLeft").delay(400).show("slide", { direction: "right", easing: 'easeOutBounce'}, 400);
}

function ScrollTwo(){
    if($("#why-use-section").visible(true)) {
        $(".slideInLeft2").delay(400).show("slide", { direction: "right", easing: 'easeOutBounce'}, 1600);
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    ScrollOne().done(ScrollTwo());
});
```