# Jquery:fade in and fade out text after a function is done loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I fade in some text while a function is called and fade out when the function is done.

I have this:

```
$(".element").click(function() {
        loadStuff($(this).text());

     });
```

say i have another class `element2` and i want it to display `"Loading"` while loadstuff is running and get out once its done..what's the simplest way to modify this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here its something like that http://jsfiddle.net/damian_silvera/24BjA/

Answer (score 0):

you can use anonymous callback in jquery ,look into this question
[Call a function after previous function is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/javascript-jquery-call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete)