# Run a function after an on.change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventhandler

I have something like this: `$('#select1').on('change', function() {})` and it works fine. However, I need to run another function after the function has completed.

I thought about taking the function contents, and putting it in a named function, then taking the second function and doing the same, and placing them in the anonymous function:

```
$('#select1').on('change', function() {
    function1 ();
    function2 ();
});
```

However, I was hoping there was another way. The above seems inconsistent with jQuery.

Comment: More information would probably be helpful here. If `function1` is a state change and `function2` updates the presentation, you might look at using publish/subscribe or the observer pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Though you could nest functions with callbacks, generally the best practice in jQuery is to use [`jQuery.Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/).

```
var function1 = function() {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    //Do your thing. When finished, call deferred.resolve()

    return deferred;
}

var function2 = function() {

   //Function 2 code
}

$('#select1').on('change', function() {

    function1().then(function2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try jquery change function insted javascript bind

$( "#select1" ).change(function() {

function1();
  function2()

});

Comment: I was hoping that i wouldn't have split them up at all. Maybe just chain the functions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#select1').on('change', function() {
    function1(someVariable, function() {
      function2(someOtherVariable);
    });
});


function function1(param, callback) {
  //...do stuff
  callback();
}
```

Here is where I found that:
[Call a function after previous function is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/javascript-jquery-call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete)

Comment: Though this works, jQuery Deferred objects are generally the recommended way to chain functions.

Comment: Unresolved function or method on() ... why i get this error