# How to wait for task to finish before moving on to next part of the code

Tags: javascript

I have a "Save" button that I need to trigger when the user clicks Next/Previous buttons on my page. When the user clicks next to move onto another window I trigger a "save" button that saves the changed the user had mad and some other functionality. The problem is when I click the next or previous button the save button is triggered but needs time to save the changes and the code keeps on executing. Is there a way I can tell whether the save has finished or delay my code somehow? I know I can do a time delay but it could be different for every user and inefficient. Here is an example:

```
function prev_next(){
     $('#save').trigger('click');     //This line could take 2-5 seconds to finish
     //Other code here that opens next window
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete

Comment: Instead of faking a click, call the underlying logic that is invoked by the click. That is presumably asynchronous, so you can do your "other code" by hanging a promise off it, or doing it in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the function that gets triggered by clicking the save button, to allow for a callback function. (I assume there is an ajax request that is sent to some server to save).

Example:

**Save function:**

```
function saveEdits(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'urltosavepage.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            somevar: 'somevalue'
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

**prev_next function:**

```
function prev_next()
{
    saveEdits(function(){
        // Code that is here will not get executed until after the ajax request is completed, and the success function gets called.
        //Other code here that opens next window
    });
}
```