# How to wait for one function to finish before continuing?

Tags: javascript

I have three functions. The calling hierarchy is like this:

```
function a() {
    b();
    c();
}

function b() {
    d();
}
```

What I want is to finish b then continue doing c. But d is asynchronous. I don't have rights to change anything in b and d. Is there any way to handle this case? Sorry for my English.

Comment: I think we need a bit more detail about the problem. Does `d()` take in a callback function? Does `d()` return a promise that you can chain to?

Comment: You can check `callbacks` or preferred option `promise`

Comment: If `d` is async, I can tell that almost async functions take callback function. If you can tell what `d` does, it'd be easier to help.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete

Comment: How exactly is the async call being done? Is it using SetInterval?

Comment: *"I don't have rights to change anything in b and d"* then your problem can't be solved.

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly not. You need a callback, a promise, or an event.

Since you can't change `b()`, you can't add a callback argument to `d()` (assuming it accepted one in the first place) and you can't capture the return value of `d()` (assuming it returned a promise in the first place).

We have no way of telling if `d()` triggers an event on the DOM  when it is done (or even if you are running the JS in a context where there is a DOM).

Comment: Can you add a callback when you call b?

Comment: @Tom — No. It doesn't pass any arguments to `d()`