# Javascript function wait until completion of recursive asynchronous function called within it

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in Javascript to wait for the completion of another function and it's callback and essentially "pause" the completion of the current function until that time?

*Example:*

```
var doSomething = function(callback) {
  doSomethingElseAsynchronously(doSomething);
  /* Wait until doSomethingElseAsynchronously */
  /* is finished and it's callback has completed */
  return callback();
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a function after previous function is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete)

Comment: Search "javascript asynchronous wait" for many answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you're thinking of is a current proposal in ES7 know as [`async` functions](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/). Their syntax looks like this:

```
async function doSomething() {
    let result = await doThingAsync(); // doThingAsync returns a Promise
    // ... Do things ...
    return result[0]
}
```

`async` functions return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolve with the eventual return value of the function.

Note that `async` functions have little to no support, and should you choose to use them, you must first transpile your code to ES6 or ES5 using something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io)