# why text() function in jquery execute before fadeOut() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Fade out a `div`
2. Change its text
3. Fade it in again

The problem is, step 2 is happening before step 1. Why is that happening?

Here's the code:

```
<p id="p">
     hi!
</p>
<button onclick="foo()">
    wefew
</button>
<script>
    $("button").click(function (){
        var item = $("#p");
        item.hide("slow");
        item.text("text");
        item.show("slow");
    })
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pq35yd5t/
edit:
I found that the problem is that I'm using a for loop and that the callback function only work on ht elast loop... why, again
code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ob_prop.length; i++) {
        if (ob_prop[i]=="tag") {
            continue;
        }
        var item = $("#"+ob_prop[i]);
        item.hide("slow", function() {
            item.text(work[pointer][ob_prop[i]]).show("slow");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a function after previous function is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because fading is an *asynchronous* operation.

To do what you're doing, use the callback on [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete):

```
$("button").click(function (){
    var item = $("#p");
    item.hide("slow", function() {
        item.text("text");
        item.show("slow");
    });
})
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> ok i have tried it but in the original code there's a for loop and function work only at the end of the loop

The callback will have `this` set to the element related to the callback, so use that rather than `item`:

```
$("button").click(function (){
    var item = $("#p");
    item.hide("slow", function() {
        $(this).text("text").show("slow");
    });
})
```

---

Your *latest* edit has the closures in loops problem. See that question's answers for details, but one of the solutions is to use `$.each` (or `Array.prototype.forEach` if you don't have to worry about obsolete browsers like IE8):

```
$.each(function(index, ob) {
    if (ob != "tag") {
        $(ob).hide("slow", function() {
            $(this).text(work[pointer][ob]).show("slow");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: ok i have tried it but in the original code there's a for loop and function work only at the end of the loop...

Comment: @S.josh: Then you'll want to use `this`; I've added to the answer.

Comment: @S.josh: That's the [closures in loops problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), nothing to do with your original code (but that happens sometimes when you do an MCVE, no worries). The answers there should sort out that aspect. I've added *one* of the options to the end of the above.