# How to call two javascript function one after the other on onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a hyperlinked image, clicking on image should call a javascript function named `downloadReport()` as given below,

```
<a href="#" title="Export" target="self"><img onclick="downloadReport()" align="right" id="exportFile" src='<c:url value="resources/img/excel_download.jpg"/>'></a>
```

again this function contains two more functions within it.

```
function downloadReport() {
    upload();
    download();

}
function upload(){
    from = getFrom();
    to =getTo();
    all = getAll();
    approved =getApproved();
    rejected = getRejected();
    pending = getPending();

    _("multiphase").method = "get";
    _("multiphase").action = "/curation/export";
    _("multiphase").submit();


}
function download(){
    _("multiphase").method = "get";
    _("multiphase").action = "/curation/download";
    _("multiphase").submit();

    }
```

Issue with this code is that, second function download() is getting called prior to upload, how to wait to complete upload function and then call download function? since i am beginner to javascript and doesn't have much information about Ajax or JQuery too.

Comment: You can use promises for that sort of asynchronous code

Comment: Download isn't being called before upload, it's being called before upload finishes since upload is async. You'll need to use a callback, or Promises, or something similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a function after previous function is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete)

Answer (score 0):

you can call first method upload() through the ajax post ajax, then on the basis of ajax success response, you can call the second method.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
function downloadReport() {
    upload().then(function() {
         download().then(function() {
             // do other stuff when all finished
         });
    });
}

function upload(){
    return $.Deferred(function(def) {
        from = getFrom();
        to = getTo();
        all = getAll();
        approved = getApproved();
        rejected = getRejected();
        pending = getPending();

        _("multiphase").method = "get";
        _("multiphase").action = "/curation/export";
        // _("multiphase").submit(); should have some sort of callback if it's async. Maybe it already returns a promise?!
        _("multiphase").submit(function(){ def.resolve(); });
        // the function(){ def.resolve(); } should represent the submit callback 
    });
}

function download() {
    return $.Deferred(function(def) {
        _("multiphase").method = "get";
        _("multiphase").action = "/curation/download";
        _("multiphase").submit(function() { def.resolve(); });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value from first function and add condition if first function execute successfully then the other one will work. something like below example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadReport() {
    var x = upload();
    if(x){
        download();
    }
}
function upload(){
    alert("Waseem");
    if(response){
        return true;    
    }
    return false;

}

function download(){
    alert("Xax");
}
</script>
```

Comment: that was a suggestion, not working code and if you follow the process (ajax success/fail function) then it will work. @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze

Comment: Maybe this should be in your answer then?