# call second function after first is complete

Tags: javascript, function

I have two functions `function1` and `function2`. I want to call the `function2` after the `function1` is complete and want to use `function1`'s return value as `function2`'s parameter

when I call these functions, the `function2` is executing first

```
var a = function1();

function2(a);
```

I checked this answer:

[Call a function after previous function is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete)

but I want to return a value from `function1` and use it in `function2`. How can I do that?

Comment: can u show us ur code

Comment: is `function1` asynchronous?

Comment: @Nick. it is not asynchronous. the first function is in another page while second function is in the same page of calling

Comment: No, `function2` will never be executing first. But maybe `function1` doesn't immediately return the result you expect. Please post their code.

Comment: @sayalok function1() is a big function which calls many google api operations like list events from google calendar , save events, update events and it took some time to return the eventId which i want to use in my second function

Comment: @Ansar So it actually *is* asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for this

```
  function f1() {

        return "value"
    }

    async function f2() {

        let result = await f1();
        console.log(result);
    }

    f2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript CallBak like this:

```
var a;

function function1(callback) {
 console.log("First comeplete");
 a = "Some value";
 callback();
}
function function2(){
 console.log("Second comeplete:", a);
}


function1(function2);
```

Or Java Script Promise:

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
  // do function1 job
  let a = "Your assign value"
  resolve(a);
});

promise.then(             

function(a) {
 // do function2 job with function1 return value;
 console.log("Second comeplete:", a);
},
function(error) { 
 console.log("Error found");
});
```

Comment: thanks for responding. but how do i get  value of "a" in function2()

Comment: try now for "a" value, Both callBack and Promise