# ReactJS Call Function after previous finisht

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can someone tell me why this doesnt work?

```
    OnSubmit = () => {
      this.SetAttributesForDTO(this.state.attributeList, this.test = () => {
          //Test Function gets called after this.SetAttributesForDTO function
      })}
```

i want a function which calls first "SetAttributesForDTO" and after that function is done, i want to call anotherone ..

Comment: I suggest you use promises, which would fulfill a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We can't help you with just the information above, we need more. Does `SetAttributesForDTO` accept a callback? Does it do its work asynchronously? Does it return a promise? Why are you assigning the function to a `test` property? Etc. :-)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder , my function doesnt accept a callback but i could implement it, never worked with callbacks but i will give it a try, it work asynchronously yes, it doesnt return any promise, and im assigning it to a test property becouse i just want to see it work

Comment: If `SetAttributesForDTO` accepts a callback as its second argument, what you have should work (though you don't need to assign the function to `this.test`). So you'll need to look into why `SetAttributesForDTO` isn't calling the callback, which we can't help you with without knowing more about that function.

Comment: Test is just a simple small test function which logs something to the console                                       test = () => {
        console.log("test");
    }

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000415/call-a-function-after-previous-function-is-complete

Comment: Thanks @LuisFernandoMontoya exactly what i need