# window load inside a document ready?

Tags: jquery, image, load, document-ready

Sorry if this has been answered before but all searches talk about the differences, not about using the two together, if possible.

Simply, can `$(window).load.(function() {})` be used INSIDE of `$(document).ready.(function() {})` ?

I have some things that should be done after the DOM is loaded but then I want to reveal certain elements only after the images have finished loading.  The only thing that works in Explorer 8, is putting the `$(window).load` functions inside of the `$(document).ready` with everything else.

Is this an acceptable practice?

I just want to use the most acceptable method to reveal a `DIV` that contains small images, like a toolbar, after it's fully constructed.  (`visibility` `hidden` versus `display` `none`, for example).  The HTML for this `DIV` is written by the code inside the `$(document).ready` and then appended to the body using `$('body').append()` before using the `$(window).load`.

I'm having lots of problems with Explorer 8.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This works fine and is an acceptable practice. After all, as you describe, there may be cases where the logic in the `$(window).load()` handler depends on work taking place after the DOM is ready. If the window is in fact already loaded by the time you set up `$(window).load()`, the handler will just fire immediately.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, it gave me the required confidence to proceed with re-writing my script into something more robust.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this problem recently... from **jQuery version 3**, we can no longer put $(window).on('load') inside document.ready()... because ready handler are called asynchronously, which means ready can be called after load.

From **jQuery Core Team**: [Github: jQuery 3 issues](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3194)

> To be clear, we understand what's causing this. We recently made ready
> handlers fire asynchronously. This has advantages that are hard to
> give up. The disadvantage is that the ready handler can sometimes fire
> after the load event if the load event fires quickly enough. The side
> effect you're seeing in this issue is that you're binding a load event
> handler after the load event has already fired.
>
> The fix is to bind the load outside of ready.
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>    // Things that need to happen when the document is ready
> });
>
> $(window).on("load", function() {
>    // Things that need to happen after full load
> });
> ```

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT:**

**NOTE: This answer is only applicable to jQuery v2 and below.**

---

[jQuery `.ready()` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> The handler passed to `.ready()` is **guaranteed** to be executed
>   **after the DOM is ready**, so this is usually the *best place to attach all other event handlers* and run other jQuery code.

[jQuery `.load()` event *method*](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> The `load` event is sent to an element **when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded**. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

Based on the jQuery documentation above, I've seen nothing that would indicate any issues with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // will fire IMMEDIATELY after the DOM is constructed

    $(window).load(function() {
        // will only fire AFTER all pages assets have loaded
    })

});
```

Placing a `.load` inside of a `ready` simply guarantees that the DOM is ready whenever the `load` is fired.

One may wish to place **all** jQuery code within a single DOM ready handler, and yet still may have a sub-set of jQuery code that requires all images be loaded first.  This arrangement guarantees that all code be triggered once on DOM ready and the rest will be triggered subsequently whenever the page assets have finished loading.

This may ultimately be more of an issue of personal preference, however the OP was clearly asking if this arrangement would cause problems.  This has not proven to be true.

Comment: This is a fantasistic answer

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work anymore in jQuery 3. The load handler won't be called.

Answer (score 5):

**WARNING**:
The answers in this question are quite outdated.

As @ViRuSTriNiTy mentioned in comments that this code is no longer valid in jQuery 3 and it was mentioned as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3194).

So this method is not advised anymore.

One way to do it is to use the following code

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
   $.ready.then(function(){
      // Both ready and loaded
   });
})
```

However, this code won't work if you load images in ready and want to call some code after it is fully loaded.

Comment: This is what I bumped into. `$(window).on("load"...` will never fire inside a `document ready` function.