# Why doesn't window onload always trigger on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a window load event contained within the document ready event that is designed to check the width of the list item that has the longest content and then apply that to each list item in a corresponding column.

I require the window load event as before adding it, the width was sometimes miscalculated. However, now with the window load event, sometimes on mobile it doesn't trigger and the content never loads.

I've tried various methods to resolve the issue, but I can't seem to get it to load 100% of the time on mobile.

There is likely another window load event in some of the third party code. I have jQuery, a smooth scroll, and a Recaptcha API. None of my code has another window load event.

```
// Select the .container--post-manager element
$(function() {    
$(window).on('load', () => {
    
   var $container = $('.container--post-manager ul');

   //Get an array of column class names
   var columnClasses = ['ids', 'status', 'titles', 'authors', 'dates'];

   //Loop through each column class
   for (var i = 0; i < columnClasses.length; i++) {
        var columnClass = columnClasses[i];

         // Find the maximum width for the current column
         var maxWidth = 0;
         $container.find('li.' + columnClass).each(function () {
             var itemWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
             maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, itemWidth);
         });
            
         //Apply greatest width to each as a min-width
         $container.find('li.' + columnClass).each(function () {
            $(this).css('min-width', (maxWidth + 20) + 'px');
         });

    }

    //Show container after window has loaded
    $('.container--post-manager').removeClass('hidden');

});
});
```

Comment: why window onload INSIDE document ready?

Comment: @GrafiCode I read somewhere it was an acceptable practice - are you suggesting that might be my problem?

Comment: according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48718000/5334486 you should declare the events without nesting