# jQuery : replacement for deprecated ".load()"?

Tags: jquery

jQuery v3.0 deprecates the `.load()` function which has me in a bind because my jQuery scripts require that images be loaded before they run.  Does anyone know a way to apply what was previously coded as

```
$(window).ready(function() {
```

but without using the `.load()` lead in?

`$(window).ready(function()` definitely does NOT work, as it triggers before the images are loaded.

I am trying to find a solution which works well with a jQuery function. I am aware of Javascript `.onload` but am not sure how to mesh that as a lead in for jQuery routines.

Thank you!

Comment: [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: Hmmm? If `load()` is deprecated, why can't you use `ready()`?

Comment: Because ready triggers before images load.

Comment: I can't find any reference in jQuery/3 release notes to changes in `.ready()`. I have the impression that whatever fails to work in version 3 didn't work either in earlier releases.

Answer (score 6):

According to http://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/:

> #### Removed deprecated event aliases
>
> `.load`, `.unload`, and `.error`, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, are no
>   more. Use `.on()` to register listeners.
>
> https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2286

Comment: OK - The specific answer is to change

to 

$(window).on("load", function() {